# Pureftpd as user,is possible?

Tags: security, chroot, pure-ftpd

I want to run pure-ftpd in chroot as user,not as root,i've set server to non privileged port 5050,but i don't know how to run as user instead of root,someone know the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some daemons (e.g.: `postfix`, `apache`) have the option to lower their operating UID after they start. It doesn't appear that `pure-ftpd` has that option.

So you need to have your distro do it. FreeBSD, for example, allows you to set the UID of each daemon in the various rc scripts.

You could also start it out of `inetd`. Using `inetd` will cause it to take longer to start when users connect; but it might be easier for you to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394984/best-practice-to-run-linux-service-as-a-different-user

it does not fully answer your question - i.e it does not provide an answer using pure-ftpd switches but gives several generic methods as well as gotchas that may be worth thinking about